# (My) PopUp Icon and DisplayIcon don't match

Tags: support, gravatar

My icon of the popup info

[image]

and my profile icon don't match

[image]

and it's been a while since a changed it. Why is that?

**EDIT**

If this continues to *work*, my next icon is
[image]

Comment: The gravatar link shows the old photo. I suspect either this is a gravatar issue (and not related to this site), or maybe you didn't upload the icon properly or something. I recall the gravatar system being somewhat uneasy.

Comment: [Works for me.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PHCfC.png) Maybe you need to clear your cache?

Comment: @RahulNarain even worse, that's the old photo :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A re-upload at gravatar solved the problem.

[image]